# Efficient Algorithm to Make Array Strictly Increasing with Segment Modifications

Tags: python, arrays

I'm working on a problem where I need to calculate the minimum number of moves required to transform an array into a strictly increasing one.  Moves involve selecting a segment of the array and increasing all of its elements by a positive integer.

Problem Description:

Given an array A of N positive integers, I want to find the minimum moves needed to make it strictly increasing (each element, except the last, is less than the next).

Constraints:

N is in the range [1..100,000]
Each element in A is within the range [1..1,000,000,000)
The array elements can exceed the upper bound of the original range after modifications.
Examples:

Input:  A = [4, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5]
Output: 2
Explanation: One solution: add 3 to the segment [2, 4] and 8 to the segment [1, 3, 5].

Input: A = [3, 5, 7, 7]
Output: 1

Input: A = [1, 5, 6, 10]
Output:  0 (already strictly increasing)

```
def solution(A):
  moves = 0
  max_so_far = A[0]

  for i in range(1, len(A)):
    current_val = A[i]
    if current_val <= max_so_far:
      diff = max_so_far + 1 - current_val
      moves += diff
      max_so_far = current_val + diff 
    else:
      max_so_far = max(max_so_far, current_val) 

  return moves

if __name__ == "__main__":
  import sys
  A = [int(x) for x in sys.argv[1:]]
  result = solution(A)
  print(result)
```

**With this code when I entered
Input: A = [3, 5, 7, 7] Output: 1
Input: A = [1, 5, 6, 10] Output: 0
it works fine,**

**but when I enter
Input:  A = [4, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5]
It returns Output: 20 which is incorrect**

**So what changes shall I need to make in a code so it will return output 2 instead of 20 for input A = [4, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5]**

Comment: It can often be helpful to find a simpler counterexample to debug algorithms like this. In this case, if `A = [2, 1]` then it outputs 2.

Comment: What about counting the number of times the current value is less or equal than the previous value? eg in `[4, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5]`  `2 <= 4` and `1 <= 4` thus only 2 times,  for `[3, 5, 7, 7]` `7<=7` thus `1` times. for `[1, 5, 6, 10]` no number is less or equal to its predecessor thus `0` times. ie you could simply do `(np.diff(array) <= 0).sum()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For debugging these types of things, it can be helpful to try and find simpler examples that nonetheless give false answers.

If we look at the simpler case, `A = [2, 1]`, we see the incorrect answer `solution([2, 1]) == 2`. Looking closer at the code, we can see:

```py
# ...
diff = max_so_far + 1 - current_val
moves += diff
# ...
```

Here we can spot a bug: instead of incrementing the moves by one when we find a segment that needs to increase, we increment them by *the difference*. For our example that leads to 2, since you need to increase 1 by 2 in order to make that array sorted.

Changing this to 1: `moves += 1`, and we can find still another counterexample: `A = [1, 1, 2]`. In this case, if we step through the logic one loop at a time, we see that it sets `max_so_far` first to 2 when it increases the second 1, but then it has to increase it once more when it runs into 2 and has a `max_so_far` of 2.

---

To fix it, the key insight (also hinted at by @Onyambu) is that we can always increase the *entire* rest of the array as one segment. Consider for a moment: if the entire array is sorted up to index `i`, that means that the value at index `i` is already the maximum we've seen, so there's no need to track `max_so_far`. But let's suppose we've increased the whole array after `i` by the same amount: the amount of items that aren't sorted in that segment is still the same as if we hadn't increased it at all. Let's consider the example:

```
[4, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5]
```

At the start, it's only sorted up to the first index. Let's mark this with `1`:

```
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

If we increase the entire array where there's `0`s by 3, we get an array sorted by two further steps:

```
[4, 5, 7, 4, 6, 8]
[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

And now we increase the latter 3 values, all by the same increment of 4:

```
[4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12]
[1, 1, 1, 1,  1,  1]
```

Critically, *the only time we need to increase is when we step back down*, because whenever we increment a section, the amount of the array sorted beyond the segment we're initially dealing with, doesn't change. Notice what happens if we only write a `1` for the places where the array doesn't increase next:

```
[4, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5]
[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

We get 1s exactly at the sorting milestones for the increase steps.

Hopefully that helps.